# How do I link to a framework according to the current build platform?

Tags: xcode

I have a [framework that’s split into two bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715195/is-it-possible-to-run-xctest-tests-in-an-ios-app). One of them supports the iPhone Simulator platform, the other supports the iPhone OS platform. And I have an app target that needs to link against this framework & embed it in the app bundle. How do I setup the build so that the app uses the iPhone OS version of the framework when building for the device and the iPhone Simulator version when building for the simulator?

Comment: Are they the same framework but just compiled for simulator and for device separately? If yes, you can use `lipo` tool to convert to universal .a in order to have an universal framework. `lipo -create simulator.a device.a -output universal.a`

Comment: It’s XCTest, so I’m not sure what the differences are. I’ll try that, thank you!

Comment: Or, you can put every lib into separate directory and change the framework search paths in your build settings.