# Programmatically run XCTests from iOS app

Tags: ios, xctest

I have a similar request as this existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715195/is-it-possible-to-run-xctest-tests-in-an-ios-app):

I like to run XCtestcases with a button click from the iOS app and display the results.

However, I have to do it in Objective-C and I am having troubles with importing the XCtestcase into the Viewcontrollers.

Can anyone advice on this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far and where do you have an issue.

Comment: I slightly reworded your question to make it easier to read.